# How to write virtual BQ table back to BQ using R DBI and bigrquery?

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbplyr, bigrquery

I want to be able to

1. Access a BQ table. This is class

```
[1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
[4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"   `
```

1. Alter the table using dbplyr to create a new table. Again, has class

```
[1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
[4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"
```

1. Write this new table to BQ.

I get the following error:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"BigQueryConnection", "character", "tbl_BigQueryConnection"’

**MRE**

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(bigrquery)

############  CREATE BQ TABLE TO ACCESS  #################
dataset = bq_dataset(bq_test_project(), "test_dataset")

if (bq_dataset_exists(dataset))
{
  bq_dataset_delete(dataset, delete_contents = T)
}
#> Suitable tokens found in the cache, associated with these emails:
#>   * ariel.balter@gmail.com
#>   * ariel.balter@providence.org
#> The first will be used.
#> Using an auto-discovered, cached token.
#> To suppress this message, modify your code or options to clearly consent to the use of a cached token.
#> See gargle's "Non-interactive auth" vignette for more details:
#> https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/non-interactive-auth.html
#> The bigrquery package is using a cached token for ariel.balter@gmail.com.

bq_dataset_create(dataset)
#> <bq_dataset> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset

conn = DBI::dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = bq_test_project(),
  dataset = "test_dataset",
  KeyFilePath = "google_service_key.json",
  OAuthMechanism = 0
)


if (dbExistsTable(conn, "mtcars"))
{
  dbRemoveTable(conn, "mtcars")
}

dbWriteTable(conn, "mtcars", mtcars)

#######################################################


### Access BQ table
mtcars_tbl = tbl(conn, "mtcars")
class(mtcars_tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
#> [4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"

### Create new virtual table
hp_gt_100_tbl = mtcars_tbl %>% filter(hp>100)
class(hp_gt_100_tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
#> [4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"

### Write new table
dbWriteTable(conn, "hp_gt_100", hp_gt_100_tbl)
#> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'dbWriteTable' for signature '"BigQueryConnection", "character", "tbl_BigQueryConnection"'

dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE mtcars")
#> [1] 0
dbExecute(conn, "DROP TABLE hp_gt_100")
#> Error: Job 'elite-magpie-257717.job_O8e7BtdfAnAb_8Vdtwybibgd7DpA.US' failed
#> x Not found: Table elite-magpie-257717:test_dataset.hp_gt_100 [notFound]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `dbWriteTable` using your current approach. `dbWriteTable` "writes, overwrites or appends a [local] data frame to a database table" ([source](https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbWriteTable.html)).

So one option is to collect that data into R and them write it back out to SQL using `dbWriteTable`. But this is likely to be inefficient.

The approach I would recommend is creating a bigquery INSERT INTO statement and passing this to `dbExecute`. Something like the following:

```r
sql_query <- glue::glue("INSERT INTO {db}.{schema}.{tbl_name}\n",
                         dbplyr::sql_render(input_tbl))

result <- dbExecute(db_connection, as.character(sql_query))
```

`sql_render` will take the definition of your current virtual table and return the text of the query. `dbExecute` will pass this command to the bigquery server to be executed.

Please note, I am not familiar enough with the `INSERT INTO` syntax for bigquery to ensure the syntax of `sql_query` above is correct, but I know the general approach works as I use dbplyr and DBI extensively in SQL server.

Comment: This definitely works, and is good to keep in my back pocket for other situations. I managed to find a way to solve the problem using `dplyr`'s `copy_to` function with the appropriate switch.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Simom.S.A 
@abalter do you care to share your solution using `dplyr`'s `copy_to` function

Answer (score 2):

I'm accepting Simon S.A.'s answer. However, I did manage to find a more direct method using a `bigrquery` function `bq_project_query`.

```r
library(DBI)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(bigrquery)

bq_deauth()
bq_auth(email="ariel.balter@gmail.com")


############  CREATE BQ TABLE TO ACCESS  #################

dataset = bq_dataset("elite-magpie-257717", "test_dataset")

if (bq_dataset_exists(dataset))
{
  bq_dataset_delete(dataset, delete_contents = T)
}
bq_dataset_create(dataset)
#> <bq_dataset> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset

conn = dbConnect(
  bigrquery::bigquery(),
  project = "elite-magpie-257717",
  dataset = "test_dataset",
  KeyFilePath = "google_service_key.json",
  OAuthMechanism = 0
)

dbWriteTable(conn, "mtcars", mtcars, overwrite=T)

dbListTables(conn)
#> [1] "mtcars"

#######################################################


### Access BQ table
mtcars_tbl = tbl(conn, "test_dataset.mtcars")
class(mtcars_tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
#> [4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"

### Create new virtual table
hp_gt00_tbl = mtcars_tbl %>% filter(hp>100)
class(hp_gt00_tbl)
#> [1] "tbl_BigQueryConnection" "tbl_dbi"                "tbl_sql"               
#> [4] "tbl_lazy"               "tbl"

hp_gt00_tbl %>% dbplyr::sql_render()
#> <SQL> SELECT *
#> FROM `test_dataset.mtcars`
#> WHERE (`hp` > 100.0)

bq_project_query(
  x = dataset$project,
  query = hp_gt00_tbl %>% dbplyr::sql_render(),
  destination = bq_table(dataset, "hp_gt_00")
)
#> <bq_table> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset.hp_gt_00

bq_dataset_tables(dataset)
#> [[1]]
#> <bq_table> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset.hp_gt_00
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <bq_table> elite-magpie-257717.test_dataset.mtcars

bq_dataset_delete(dataset, delete_contents = T)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>